# Returning an object's index by dictionary value

Tags: objective-c

Here is my scenario: 
I have an array of dictionary items with 2 values.

```
array = (
    {
        id = 1;
        title = "Salon One";
    },
    {
        id = 2;
        title = "Salon Two";
    }
)
```

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but can I pass this array into a function and return an objects index based on a dictionary value?

```
- (int)getObjectIndex:(NSMutableArray *)array byName:(NSString *)theName{
    int index;

    /* Pseudo Code*/
    /*index = the index value in 'array' of objectForKey:@"title" = theName*/

    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not?

```
- (NSInteger)getObjectIndex:(NSMutableArray *)array byName:(NSString *)theName {
    NSInteger idx = 0;
    for (NSDictionary* dict in array) {
        if ([[dict objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:theName])
            return idx;
        ++idx;
    }
    return NSNotFound;
}
```

Note the slight difference in the signature (return type `NSInteger` vs `int`). This is necessary when using NSNotFound in 64 bit environments.

Comment: However, I'd suggest renaming the method `-indexOfObjectInArray:byTitle:` instead. Using "get" as the prefix in Cocoa implies return by reference.

Comment: Wonderful. I had a for loop, but it wasn't in the for each form that you have it in. Still trying to get myself accustomed to the syntax.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to go super-fancy with blocks introduced in Snow Leopard, you could do:

```
- (BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))blockTestingForTitle:(NSString*)theName {
    return [[^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([[obj objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:theName]) {
            *stop = YES;
            return YES;
        }
        return NO;
    } copy] autorelease];
}
```

and then whenever you want to find the index of a dictionary in an array:

```
[array indexOfObjectPassingTest:[self blockTestingForTitle:@"Salon One"]]
```

Comment: This strategy is better than enumerating the array yourself since it gives NSArray the chance to run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible, just loop through the array until you find the thing you're looking for